# how to store image in database using laravel 5.3 by passing data with ajax in controller?

Tags: php, ajax, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I've create one form which is given below
html code:

```
<form method="post" class="inline" id="upload_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input style="margin-top:0px;" type="file" name="data1"  id="file1" class="btn btn-block btn-primary"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" id="token">
        <a href="#" id="submit">link submit</a>
</form>
```

ajax code:

```
function create()
{

         alert();
         var file = document.getElementById('file1');
         var token = document.getElementById('token').value;
         var data1 = new FormData($("#upload_form")[0]);
         var route = "http://localhost:8080/form";
         console.log(FormData);
         console.log(data1);



         $.ajax({
                    type:'POST',
                    url: route,
                    headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token},
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    data:{
                                'data1': data1,
                         },
                    success:function(e){
                        if(e == 0)  
                        {
                             alert("Success Full Created"); 

                        }
                        else
                        {   
                             alert("Error");
                        }
                    }
                 });
         }
```

This is my route :

```
Route::post('form', 'StoreController@newstore');
```

I've created controller which is given below 
Controller :

```
public function newstore(Request $request)
{
   $post = $request->file('data1');
   dd($post);
   //If there is error try dd($post) and let me know 
   // we need know if the data file image is passing to controller
   $imageName =  $post->getClientOriginalName();
   $imagemove= $post->move(public_path('images'),$imageName);
   $data123 = array (   "photo"=> $imageName,  );
   $check222 = DB::table('product') -> insert($data123);    
}
```

when i run this code its show me this error : 
    MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218:

Comment: After $formData in your function create () please insert console.log ($formData); open your console broswer  and let us the result

Comment: I got this statment in console log: FormData
__proto__
:
FormData
append
:
append()
constructor
:
FormData()
delete
:
delete()
entries
:
entries()
forEach
:
forEach()
get
:
get()
getAll
:
getAll()
has
:
has()
keys
:
keys()
set
:
set()
values
:
values()
Symbol(Symbol.iterator)
:
()
Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag)
:
"FormData"
__proto__
:
Object

Comment: Ok try to change your type: 'get' to type: 'POST'

Comment: After changing type its shows me : Undefined index: data1

Comment: Submit file with your network broswer open, maybe it need csfr token,

Comment: Is there any need for token..!! as per my information its only use to provide security.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<form method="post" class="inline" id="upload_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input style="margin-top:0px;" type="file" name="data1"  id="file1" class="btn btn-block btn-primary"/>
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" id="token">
<a href="#" id="submit">link submit</a>
</form>
```

if for example your route is:

```
Route::post('form', 'yourcontroller@newstore');
```

JS

```
function create()
{

 var file = document.getElementById('file1');
 var route = "http://localhost:8000/form";
 var token = document.getElementById('token').value;
 var data1 = new FormData($("#upload_form")[0]);
 // we are using "$", i hope that you have jquery library 
/* alternative you can do:
   var getUpload = document.queryselector('#upload_form');
   var data1 = getUpload[0];
*/ 

//if there is error try also console.log(formData)
// if error try console-log(data1); info about the file uploaded
// if error token verify console.log(token); have the token serial number


$.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url: route,
        headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token},
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data:{
                    'data1': data1,
             },
        success:function(e){
            if(e == 0)  
            {
                 alert("Success Full Created"); 

            }
            else
            {   
                 alert("Error");
            }
        }
});}
var submit = document.querySelector('#submit').onclick= create
```

CONTROLLER

```
public function newstore(Request $request)
{
   $post = $request->file('data1');
   //If there is error try dd($post) and let me know 
   // we need know if the data file image is passing to controller
   $imageName =  $post->getClientOriginalName();
   $imagemove= $post->move(public_path('images'),$imageName);
   $data123 = array (   "photo"=> $imageName,  );
   $check222 = DB::table('product') -> insert($data123);   
}
```

Let me know if you get some error! i hope it work!

Comment: I've tried your code but shows me this error : MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218:

Comment: If i pass the data instead of image or file it works fine with this code but when i pass the file or image it doesnt work.

Comment: Use a link <link href="#" id="submit" > to submit because if you use a button it will submit the form and the action route will not work. This is the reason because you have error route collection.

Comment: do a event click on click link, for example: var submit = document.querySelector('#submit').onclick= create; add link submit and add this js after your function create

Comment: Its shows me same error which showed before "Router collection". after running a code i noticed that it data is not even passed to controller.